# populating sql database from gridview checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, checkbox

I am trying to add a checkbox to the end of the gridview section that once checked it updates the sql database with a "1" or "0". Yes the it is done in bit with column name posFill.

Here is code....

```
protected void gvPerson_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconnection"].ToString()))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


            cmd.Connection = conn;


            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE requests SET date = @date, submitted_by = @submitted_by, position = @position, district = @district, base_store = @base_store, travel_to = @travel_to, open_til6 = @open_til6, email_add = @email_add, comments = @comments, posFill = @posFill, interviewDate = @interviewDate  WHERE _id = @_id";


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // Get the PersonID of the selected row.
            string strID = gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
            string strPosition = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
            string strEmail_add = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
            string strDate = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3")).Text;
            string strSubBy = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;
            string strDist = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox5")).Text;
            string strBase = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox6")).Text;
            string strTravel = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox7")).Text;
            string strOpen = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox8")).Text;
            string strComments = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox9")).Text;
            //string strFilled = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox10")).Text;
            string strIntDate = ((TextBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox11")).Text;
            string strLblFilled = ((Label)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblFilled")).Text;

            // Append the parameters.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = strID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@position", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strPosition;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email_add", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strEmail_add;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = strDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@submitted_by", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strSubBy;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@district", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strDist;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@base_store", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strBase;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@travel_to", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strTravel;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@open_til6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strOpen;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strComments;
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@posFilled", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strFilled;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@interviewDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = strIntDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@posFill", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = strLblFilled;

            // Open the connection.
            conn.Open();

            // Execute the command.
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // Exit edit mode.
        gvPerson.EditIndex = -1;

        // Rebind the GridView control to show data after updating.
        BindGridView();

        // Show the Add button.
        lbtnAdd.Visible = true;
    }
```

Here is the function for the checkbox...

```
protected void posFilled_CheckChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkFilled.Checked == true)
        { lblFilled.Text = "1"; }
        else
        { lblFilled.Text = "0"; }


    }
```

the checkbox is on the gridview and functioning but here is the code for it too.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Filled" SortExpression="posFill">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFilled" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFilled" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("posFilled") %>'></asp:TextBox>--%>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFilled2" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFilled" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                    <%--<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("posFilled") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

thank you in advance. i added a label to see what the response would be or if it even responded and if it did then just use label contents. but would rather not.

Comment: Is there a question? Please clearly state what it is you are asking

Comment: I am trying to add a checkbox to the end of the gridview section that once checked it updates the sql database with a "1" or "0". Yes the it is done in bit with column name posFill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "1".ToString() or "0".ToString(), why don't you just use the control itself?  You don't need the label.

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@posFill", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkFilled.Checked;
```

EDIT:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@posFill", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ((CheckBox)gvPerson.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkFilled")).Checked;
```

EDIT2:

You only have one int column.  You should do this to make sure you're putting in a value that matches the datatype of the parameter:

```
 int tempInt = -1;

 if (int.TryParse(strID, out tempInt))
 {
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tempInt;

      cmd.ExecuteNonquery();
 }
```

In fact, you should validate all of your data before you attempt to execute the command.  You should be assigning all of your parameters the correct data types.  If you're passing a SqlDbType.Date, you should pass it a DateTime variable and it should actually parse out as a DateTime.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried that but for some ungodly reason whenever i put that in there im getting chkFilled.Checked does not exist in current context.

Comment: I've edited my response.  That should now give you the CheckBox you need within that specific row.  Let me know if that works for you.  If you can find your label and get its text, then you should be able to find your CheckBox and get whether or not it's checked.  =)

Comment: I believe this is working BUT.... when i submit the update it is kicking out a cant convert string to int32 error.

Comment: You only have one int column.  You should do this to make sure you're putting in a value that matches the datatype of the parameter:

int tempInt = -1;

if (int.TryParse(strID, out tempInt))
{
command.ExecuteNonquery();
}

In fact, you should validate all of your data before you attempt to execute the command.

Comment: thats what im not understanding because up until i added the checkbox and the line that you suggested everything worked flawlessly. im wondering if its tied to the "bit" in the database for posFill. and when the checkbox is checked it just does true or false. correct?

Comment: actually i just added your edit. and now im not getting the error anymore but its not updating anything in the posFill section of the database

Comment: Ok i have worked through all the other issues AND your recommendation WORKED like a charm problem solved. Thanks alot G3n1us